# Android apk downloaded from GooglePlay crashes after update in Firmware 4.1.1

Tags: android, crash, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a game in Google Play. It have been working fine in the previous 3 updates. But in the 4th after you download and install the update the game crashes only in Android 4.1.1 devices.

It happens because somehow GooglePlay installed incorrectly the application and the native library is not correctly set up.

Reading some Google forms I believe this is know problem of that android firmware. I already worked around that by saving the native library in the res files and coping it to `/data/data/com.minix.android.Game/files` and loading it from there. Yet the players lost all of their progress, like if the corrupt installation clears the game data.

```
02-28 15:40:49.050: W/dalvikvm(23159): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError;     thrown while initializing Lcom/minix/android/Game;
02-28 15:40:49.050: W/dalvikvm(23159): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/minix/android/Game;)
02-28 15:40:49.050: D/AndroidRuntime(23159): Shutting down VM
02-28 15:40:49.050: W/dalvikvm(23159): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410382a0)
02-28 15:40:49.050: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2465): setHidden false
02-28 15:40:49.050: D/WindowManager(2465): mInputFocus is not null.
02-28 15:40:49.050: D/WindowManager(2465): mInputFocus is not null.
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load minix: findLibrary returned null
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    at com.minix.android.Game.GameActivity <clinit>(Unknown Source)
02-28 15:40:49.050: E/AndroidRuntime(23159):    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons that might cause this:

- You don't have this in your code:

static {
   System.loadLibrary("mylibraryname");
}

- You changed your package name in the code or in the package itself and they don't match.
- You use an expired or invalid signature to sign your app.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. The System.loadLibrary() is there in my code, it works perfectly for any version but 4.1.1. Package name hasn't change and signature works on other firmwares.